# Matrix-chain Multiplication and a bit different problems?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, dynamic-programming, matrix-multiplication

We know Matrix-chain Multiplication Problem. My professor solve one close problem as:

> We want to find an order of Matrix multiplication such that number of
>   elements in middle matrixes (calculated in all steps of production) is
>   minimized (we called it cost of production). We have
>   A_1*A_2*A_3*...* A_n and dimension A_i is on d_{i-1} and d_i. C_{ij} =
>   min cost of production A_i*...*A_j sub problems and C_{ii}=0.  he says
>   the relation for solving this problem is:

```
C_{ij}=min i<=k < j  max{C_{ik}, C_{k+1,j}, d_{i-1}*d_j}
```

I couldent get it, what is the idea behind  this relation? how can help me ?

Comment: Is this really a programming question? Maybe the [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) site would be better qualified to help.

Comment: More like computer science. Run-time complexity, discrete optimization, probably heuristic algorithms.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that we want to minimize `C(i, j)`. What can we choose? We can choose the position of the **last** multiplication we will perform. When it is fixed, we have two independent subproblems(everything before the last multiplication and everything after it). So the equation `C_{ij}=min i<=k < j  max{C_{ik}, C_{k+1,j}, d_{i-1}*d_j}` in plain English means:

1. Let's choose the position of the last multiplication and denote it is `k`.
2. Let's solve two subproblems: one for `(i, k)` and another one for `(k + 1, j)`.
3. For a fixed `k`, the answer is maximum of the results for these two subproblems and the size of the final matrix which we get after multiplying all matrices in `(i, j)` range(namely, `d_{i-1}*d_j`, and it does not depend on the order of multiplication).
4. We want to minimize the result, so we choose the smallest value among all valid `k`.

That's it.

Comment: so why C_{ij}=min i<=k < j  max{C_{ik}, C_{k+1,j} + d_{i-1}*d_j} this is not selected?

Comment: @Prof.KosiNoura What is not selected? We do select k which yeilds the smallest value(by taking min).

Comment: sorry, I means why we cannot for example use  this formula C_{ij}=min i<=k < j max{C_{ik}, C_{k+1,j} + d_{i-1}*d_j}? adding dimension with cost. please see this formula carefully.  or C_{ij}=min i<=k < j max{C_{ik}, C_{k+1,j}} + d_{i-1}*d_j ?

Comment: @Prof.KosiNoura We want to minimize the size of the largest matrix, not the sum(according to the problem statement).

Comment: another problem arises, why "For a fixed k, the answer is maximum of the results for these two subproblems and size of final matrix?

Comment: @Prof.KosiNoura It directly follows from the problem statement. What intermidiate results do we have? All intermidiate results for subproblems and the final matrix.

Comment: I think smaller intermeidiate result we want ! not maximum. please clarify it for me.

Comment: @Prof.KosiNoura We want to minimize the maximum of all intermediate results. When we fix `k`, the result does not depend on us anymore. We have to take the maximum according to the problem statement. The fact the we want to minimize the answer is expressed by the fact that we take minimum over all valid `k`.

Comment: would you please continue in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73986/discussion-between-prof-kosi-noura-and-kraskevich).